# Equivalent expression for “good timing”

Tags: expressões, expressões-equivalentes

In English there is an expression *"good timing"* which means that some event happened at the right time or that multiple events happened at the same time (when desirable).

Examples:

> One of the secrets of cricket is good timing.
>
> You arrived just when I needed you - good timing!

---

**What would be a natural way to translate *"good timing"* to Portuguese?**

Google Translate suggests *"cronometragem boa"* which sounds really strange and technical to me and *"bom timing"* which made me laugh but not very certain about it's validity ;)

Comment: What does it mean in English?

Comment: @Math edited :)

Comment: I am not a native english speaker therefore edits are encouraged if anyone feels like improving my explanation of the expression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that are several different possible translations for that, but I believe that best one is:

### Sincronismo

> [en] One of the secrets of cricket is good timing.
>   [pt] Um dos segredos do cricket é o bom sincronismo.

For the example below, "sincronismo" works well, but it seems too technical. Perhaps a more colloquial way to say so would be:

### Bem na hora

> [en] You arrived just when I needed you - good timing!
>   [pt] Você chegou bem quando eu precisava de você - bem na hora!

The following doesn't seem so natural, but also works:

> [pt] Você chegou bem quando eu precisava de você - bem sincronizado!

Answer (score 1):

There is no word for this in Spanish, so I have my doubts that Portuguese has one.  Though i could be completely wrong.

### momento perfeito

is the best I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the most "approximate" terms are:

- Hora certa

  Eg. Você chegou na *hora certa*.
- Boa hora

  Eg. Esse dinheiro veio em *boa hora*.
- Oportuno

  Eg. Acho que o momento era oportuno.